# Pretty print json but keep inner arrays on one line python

Tags: python, arrays, json, dictionary, pretty-print

I am pretty printing a json in Python using this code:

```
json.dumps(json_output, indent=2, separators=(',', ': ')
```

This prints my json like:

```
{    
    "rows_parsed": [
        [
          "a",
          "b",
          "c",
          "d"
        ],
        [
          "e",
          "f",
          "g",
          "i"
        ],
    ]
}
```

However, I want it to print like:

```
{    
    "rows_parsed": [
        ["a","b","c","d"],
        ["e","f","g","i"],
    ]
}
```

How can I keep the arrays that are in arrays all on one line like above?

Comment: Note that your desired output does not keep _all_ arrays on one line.

Comment: Great point. Let me clarify my question.

Comment: (Easy:) consider `pprint`. (Hard:) consider writing a custom JSONEncoder and pass it as `cls` argument to `dumps`. (Obligatory:) think again why you need this all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON dumps custom formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16264515/json-dumps-custom-formatting)

Comment: Do you want to keep "arrays that are in arrays" all on one line, or do you really want to keep *arrays that doesn't contain other arrays or dicts* on one line? The latter seems like a more natural thing to want.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a way to do it with as least amount of modifications as possible:

```
import json
from json import JSONEncoder
import re

class MarkedList:
    _list = None
    def __init__(self, l):
        self._list = l

z = {    
    "rows_parsed": [
        MarkedList([
          "a",
          "b",
          "c",
          "d"
        ]),
        MarkedList([
          "e",
          "f",
          "g",
          "i"
        ]),
    ]
}

class CustomJSONEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, MarkedList):
            return "##<{}>##".format(o._list)

b = json.dumps(z, indent=2, separators=(',', ':'), cls=CustomJSONEncoder)
b = b.replace('"##<', "").replace('>##"', "")

print(b)
```

Basically the lists that you want formatted in that way you make instance of
`MarkedList` and they get parsed as strings with hopefully unique enough sequence
that is later stripped from the output of `dumps`. This is done to eliminate the quotes that are put around a json string.

Another much more efficient way to do it, but a much more ugly one is to monkey patch
`json.encoder._make_iterencode._iterencode` with something like:

```
def _iterencode(o, _current_indent_level):
    if isinstance(o, str):
        yield _encoder(o)
    elif o is None:
        yield 'null'
    elif o is True:
        yield 'true'
    elif o is False:
        yield 'false'
    elif isinstance(o, int):
        # see comment for int/float in _make_iterencode
        yield _intstr(o)
    elif isinstance(o, float):
        # see comment for int/float in _make_iterencode
        yield _floatstr(o)
    elif isinstance(o, MarkedList):
        yield _my_custom_parsing(o)
    elif isinstance(o, (list, tuple)):
        yield from _iterencode_list(o, _current_indent_level)
    elif isinstance(o, dict):
        yield from _iterencode_dict(o, _current_indent_level)
    else:
        if markers is not None:
            markerid = id(o)
            if markerid in markers:
                raise ValueError("Circular reference detected")
            markers[markerid] = o
        o = _default(o)
        yield from _iterencode(o, _current_indent_level)
        if markers is not None:
            del markers[markerid]
```

Comment: `"##<{}>##".format(o._list)` doesn't work if the list contains None, and also renders single quotes which aren't valid json.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how you could do it in the json.dumps. After a bit of searching I came across a few options:
One option would be to do some post-processing with a custom function:

```
def fix_json_indent(text, indent=3):
            space_indent = indent * 4
    initial = " " * space_indent
    json_output = []
    current_level_elems = []
    all_entries_at_level = None  # holder for consecutive entries at exact space_indent level
    for line in text.splitlines():
        if line.startswith(initial):
            if line[space_indent] == " ":
                # line indented further than the level
                if all_entries_at_level:
                    current_level_elems.append(all_entries_at_level)
                    all_entries_at_level = None
                item = line.strip()
                current_level_elems.append(item)
                if item.endswith(","):
                    current_level_elems.append(" ")
            elif current_level_elems:
                # line on the same space_indent level
                # no more sublevel_entries 
                current_level_elems.append(line.strip())
                json_output.append("".join(current_level_elems))
                current_level_elems = []
            else:
                # line at the exact space_indent level but no items indented further
                if all_entries_at_level:
                    # last pending item was not the start of a new sublevel_entries.
                    json_output.append(all_entries_at_level)
                all_entries_at_level = line.rstrip()
        else:
            if all_entries_at_level:
                json_output.append(all_entries_at_level)
                all_entries_at_level = None
            if current_level_elems:
                json_output.append("".join(current_level_elems))
            json_output.append(line)
    return "\n".join(json_output)
```

Another possibility is a regex but it is quite ugly and depends on the structure of the code you posted:

```
def fix_json_indent(text):
    import re
    return  re.sub('{"', '{\n"', re.sub('\[\[', '[\n[', re.sub('\]\]', ']\n]', re.sub('}', '\n}', text))))
```