# pandas.to_json suppress indentation for lists as values

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a DataFrame with lists in one column.
I want to pretty print the data as JSON.

How can I use indentation without affecting the values in each cell to be indented.

An example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(range(3))
df["lists"] = [list(range(i+1)) for i in range(3)]
print(df)
```

output:

```
   0      lists
0  0        [0]
1  1     [0, 1]
2  2  [0, 1, 2]
```

Now I want to print the data as JSON using:

```
print(df.to_json(orient="index", indent=2))
```

output:

```
{
  "0":{
    "0":0,
    "lists":[
      0
    ]
  },
  "1":{
    "0":1,
    "lists":[
      0,
      1
    ]
  },
  "2":{
    "0":2,
    "lists":[
      0,
      1,
      2
    ]
  }
}
```

desired output:

```
{
  "0":{
    "0":0,
    "lists":[0]
  },
  "1":{
    "0":1,
    "lists":[0,1]
  },
  "2":{
    "0":2,
    "lists":[0,1,2]
  }
}
```

Comment: They are the same.

Comment: To a computer they are the same. To a human the use of too much indentation is contra productive.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26264742/pretty-print-json-but-keep-inner-arrays-on-one-line-python

Comment: @braml1 I would argue this is a different question, because it's specifically about `pandas.DataFrame.to_json`. But since it's hard to achieve even with just the JSON package, I don't have high hopes to get an answer here.

Comment: As you probably also found: the `pandas.DataFrame.to_json` API (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) does not support the functionality you are looking for

Comment: Still the duplicate of it. you can still use them to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to bother with json format output, you can just turn the list type to string temporarily when printing the dataframe

```py
print(df.astype({'lists':'str'}).to_json(orient="index", indent=2))
```

```
{
  "0":{
    "0":0,
    "lists":"[0]"
  },
  "1":{
    "0":1,
    "lists":"[0, 1]"
  },
  "2":{
    "0":2,
    "lists":"[0, 1, 2]"
  }
}
```

If you don't want to see the quote mark, you use regex to replace them

```py
import re

import re
result = re.sub(r'("lists":)"([^"]*)"', r"\1 \2",
                df.astype({'lists':'str'}).to_json(orient="index", indent=2))
```

```
{
  "0":{
    "0":0,
    "lists": [0]
  },
  "1":{
    "0":1,
    "lists": [0, 1]
  },
  "2":{
    "0":2,
    "lists": [0, 1, 2]
  }
}
```