# Parse json data in python

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x

I am having trouble parsing the resulting json data to return only wanted section (e.g., 'name, 'aisle', 'status'). How can I modify the output to only print those items?

Code:

```
    for coro in tqdm(asyncio.as_completed(tasks, loop=loop)):
    try:
        response = await coro
        if response is None:
            continue
        data, store = response
        result = json.loads(data['searchResults'])['results'][0]
        summary = {
            'name': result['name'],
            'aisle': result['price']['aisle'][0],
            'status': result['inventory']['status'],
        }
        results[store] = summary
    except (IndexError, KeyError):
        continue

   with open('Testing.txt', 'w') as outfile:
   json.dump(results, outfile, indent = 2)
   outfile.write('\n')
```

When I print I get the following format:

```
{
  "1": {
    "name": "camera",
    "aisle": "M.3",
    "status": "In Stock"
  },
   "2": {
    "name": "camera",
    "aisle": "M.53",
    "status": "Out of Stock"  
  },
   "3":{
    "name": "camera",
    "aisle": "M.32",
    "status": "In Stock"
  }
}
```

I would like the output for each loop on a single line, such as:

```
    '35': { 'name': 'Camera', 'aisle': 'M.35', 'status': 'Out of stock' },
    '36': { 'name': 'Camera', 'aisle': 'J.35', 'status': 'In stock' }
```

Comment: Have you read the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) docs by any chance? They explain how to convert JSON data into Python dicts, then you simply need to access the appropriate dict elements and print them however you like.

Comment: In that case you better to off using json and just joining the items and write them to a text file.

Comment: Thanks - I updated my post above but am getting the following error: NameError: name 'data' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

FYI—the sample data from the output file looks wrong because the value string is not valid json.  It should be like this:

```
"{\"results\":[{\"name\":\"Camera\",\"department\":{\"name\":\"Electronics\",\"storeDeptId\":-1},\"location\":{\"aisle\":[\"M.35\"],\"detailed\":[{\"zone\":\"M\",\"aisle\":\"36\",\"section\":\"2\"}]},\"price\":{\"priceInCents\":49900,\"isRealTime\":true,\"currencyUnit\":\"USD\"},\"inventory\":{\"quantity\":3,\"status\":\"Out of stock\",\"isRealTime\":true}}]}"
```

Note the `]` that is in my version of your JSON but not in yours.  Once you get to valid JSON, you can use json.loads to transform that JSON string into a value that you can pull data out of:

```
data = json.loads(data['searchResults'])
print json.dumps(data, indent=2)
```

which should get you:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "department": {
        "name": "Electronics",
        "storeDeptId": -1
      },
      "inventory": {
        "status": "Out of stock",
        "isRealTime": true,
        "quantity": 3
      },
      "price": {
        "priceInCents": 49900,
        "isRealTime": true,
        "currencyUnit": "USD"
      },
      "name": "Camera",
      "location": {
        "detailed": [
          {
            "aisle": "36",
            "section": "2",
            "zone": "M"
          }
        ],
        "aisle": [
          "M.35"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, something like this will get you close to the trimmed output you want:

```
for coro in asyncio.as_completed(tasks, loop=loop):
    try:
        data, store = await coro
        result = json.loads(data['searchResults'])['results'][0] #Storing retrieved json data
        summary = {
            'name': result['name'],
            'aisle': result['location']['aisle'][0],
            'status': result['inventory']['status'],
        }
        results[store] = summary
    except (IndexError):
        continue
```

After this, the output in your output file will look something like:

```
'35': { 'name': 'Camera', 'aisle': 'M.35', 'status': 'Out of stock' },
```

Comment: Thanks - I updated my post above but am getting the following error: NameError: name 'data' is not defined

Comment: The last two lines of your updated code block are not needed.  Replace them with your original code for outputting the txt file.

Comment: How could I modify the 'write to file' so that the results of each loop are on individual lines? Right now I am getting a new line for each data point.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16264515/json-dumps-custom-formatting