# JSON Dumps Better Dictionary Formatting

Tags: python, json, jsonencoder

I would like to improve / customize json dumps to improve clarity of outputs.

When I run:

```
import json

d = {
       'a': 1,
       'b': 2,
       'c': {
               'x': 9,
               'y': 8,
               'z': 7
            },
       'd': 3
    }

print(json.dumps(d, indent = 2))
```

The output is:

```
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
  "c": {
    "x": 9,
    "y": 8,
    "z": 7
  },
  "d": 3
}
```

I would like the output to instead be:

```
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
  "c": {
         "x": 9,
         "y": 8,
         "z": 7
       },
  "d": 3
}
```

I know it seems like a small change, but especially for larger dumps with multiple nested dictionaries, I believe that this will greatly improve clarity of outputs.

I have read a bit about custom JSON encoders such as what is suggested here: [JSON dumps custom formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16264515/json-dumps-custom-formatting)
but I have been unable to find anything I can customize for my application.

Any and all assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you be more explicit about the changes you expect ? I see two: bigger indent, and closing `}` indentation match the opening bracket.

Comment: Have you looked into `pprint`?

Comment: Yes, @GrégoireRoussel I would like to implement both of those changes

Comment: Yes @JohnGordon I have looked into pprint, it works well for lists but I have not found any functionality for dictionaries, plus it would be nice to be able to log to a json file using this format